# Capistrano cap production deploy fails on migration but cap production deploy:migrate passes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano3

I've come across a strange problem with Capistrano while getting a production server ready. When I run `cap production deploy`, it always fails on the deploy:migrate step with

> ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not
>   configured. Available: ["defaul…

Yet, when I run `cap production deploy:migrate`, Capistrano completes successfully.

On the actual server, I am able to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake:migrate` without any problems either.

The Capistrano log spits out the same command for both:

> [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`

My database config looks like this:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: foo
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: bar
  password: password
  socket: /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

I should also mention that I have set the rails env in my deploy.rb like so: `set :rails_env, :production`

Here is the relevent information in my gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.5'
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.6', '>= 3.6.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
end
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I am missing here? I am new to Capistrano.

Comment: Is there a chance that when it pulls out latest code (new folder ...) it tries to run the migrations before database.yml is properly set up?

Comment: Based on the log I do not believe this is happening, I can see it running the git commands etc 6 steps before the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found the root cause.

I didn't realise that the "current" directory (or symlink to be fair) is created at the end of the Capistrano process and since I had an earlier trial run with RAKE_ENV=development, I already had the current symlink on the server.

Before the deploy:migrate step, I upload my database.yml from a secure location to the server via a custom task that uses this command:

```
upload! "#{SECURE_DATA}database.yml", "#{current_path}/config/"
```

Which at the time of before deploy:migrate, which to my confusion, I thought the rake db:migrate was being run from the current symlink, but it was in fact being run from the latest release directory. The latest release directory did not have the production database information as the file was uploaded to the current symlink which pointed to an old release.

All in all, my custom task caused this problem and if anyone else comes across a similar scenario, us this command instead:

```
upload! "#{SECURE_DATA}database.yml", "#{release_path}/config/"
```

The key being the `release_path` variable instead of the `current_path` variable.